# How do I stop using root privileges?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, root, su

I know this is extremely basic, but I am using Ubuntu Linux and I have just typed in

> sudo su

I entered my password and performed the actions that I had to get done. Now how do I stop being root and go back to being a normal user? I'm afraid I'll mess something up like `rm -rf /`.

Comment: You mean like this? http://blog.utest.com/how-pixar-almost-deleted-toy-story-2/2012/05/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User privileges are associated with processes. In this case, your superuser privileges are associated with the shell that ran when you did `sudo su`. You need to exit that shell. To do that use the aptly-named `exit` command.

If you haven't messed with the prompt definitions, superuser status is indicated by a `#` in the prompt instead of the user's `$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Immediately after writing my question, I tried "su my_name", because I realized it stands for substitute user. I also thought it worked, until I tried "exit" as you suggested, haha.

Comment: Also you can use hot key combination 'Ctrl+D' to to exit superuser shell.

Answer (score 1):

When you `su`, a new login shell is started for the root user; to drop root privilege and go back to your usual login, simply `logout` or hit Control-D.